# Your environment may not have any index with Wazuh's alerts

Tags: kibana, elk, wazuh

I'm getting this error when I am trying to reinstall elk with wazuh

Answer (score 1):

We need more precise information about your use case in order to help you to troubleshoot this problem.

I recommend you follow the uninstallation guide from the official documentation https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/uninstall/elastic-stack.html, and after that, install it again https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/more-installation-alternatives/elastic-stack/all-in-one-deployment/unattended-installation.html.

If you want to preserve your configuration make sure to backup the following files

```
   cp -p  /var/ossec/etc/ /var/ossec_backup/etc/client.keys
   cp -p /var/ossec/etc/  /var/ossec_backup/etc/ossec.conf 
   cp -p  /var/ossec/queue/rids/sender_counter /var/ossec_backup/queue/rids/sender_counter
```

If you have made local changes to any of the following then also backup them:

```
cp -p /var/ossec/etc/local_internal_options.conf /var/ossec_backup/etc/local_internal_options.conf 
cp -p  /var/ossec/etc/rules/local_rules.xml /var/ossec_backup/rules/local_rules.xml
cp -p  /var/ossec/etc/decoders/local_decoder.xml /var/ossec_backup/etc/local_decoder.xml
```

If you have the centralized configuration you must preserve:

cp -p /var/ossec/etc/shared/default/agent.conf /var/ossec_backup/etc/shared/agent.conf

Optionally the following files can be restored to preserve alert log files and syscheck/rootcheck databases:

```
cp -rp  /var/ossec/logs/archives /var/ossec_backup/logs/archives/*
cp -rp /var/ossec/logs/alerts  /var/ossec_backup/logs/alerts/*
cp -rp  /var/ossec/queue/rootcheck /var/ossec_backup/queue/rootcheck/*
cp -rp  /var/ossec/queue/syscheck /var/ossec_backup/queue/syscheck/*
```

After reinstalling, you need to place those files in their original path.

Also, in case you want to preserve your indexes after restarting consider making a backup of your indexes following this blog  https://wazuh.com/blog/index-backup-management/.